# Retrieving an up to date remote branch commit hash without fetching

Tags: git

Is there a command (something like git remote show maybe) that will get me an up to date remote branch commit hash without updating references by fetching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
git ls-remote <URL> <BRANCH>
```

and you will get following output:

```
λ git ls-remote https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit.git master
b5d2137d95d861ede02188dcbc7cdc459562d706        refs/heads/master
```

see help page: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Wanted to point out that you can replace that URL with a remote name and it still works.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
git log origin/<branch> -1
```

Comment: That's not up to date. That command just reads the local references.

Comment: Correct! I just realized that.